# Troubleshooting ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY

Tags: debugging, memory-management, out-of-memory

Our application is failing on one specific user's computer with `ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY` ("Not enough storage is available to process this command").

The error is apparently being raised somewhere deep within the Delphi VCL framework that we're using, so I'm not sure which Windows API function is responsible.

**Is memory a problem?**  A call to [`GlobalMemoryStatus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366586%28VS.85%29.aspx) gives the following information:

- dwTotalPhys - 1063150000 (~1 GB)
- dwAvailPhys - 26735000 (~27 MB)
- dwAvailPage - 1489000000 (~1.4 GB)

It seems strange to me that Windows would let the available physical memory get so low when so much space is available in the paging file, but I don't know enough about Windows' virtual memory management to know if this is normal or not.  Is it?

**If not memory, then which resource limit is being hit?** From what I read online, `ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY` could be the result of the application hitting any of several limits (GDI objects, USER objects, handles, etc.) and not necessarily memory.  Is there a comprehensive list of what limits Windows enforces?  Is there any way to find out which limit is being hit?  I tried Google, but I couldn't find any systematic overview.

Comment: GDI is my first port of call. While it's odd that it's only happening on one user's machine, that's where I'd start. It could also be something like number of handles that are in use, etc. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit in this case was [CreateCompatibleBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183488%28VS.85%29.aspx).  Apparently Windows may enforce fairly strict systemwide limits on the memory available for device-dependent bitmaps (see, e.g, [this mailing list discussion](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/30977689/limits-on-size-of-bitmap.aspx)), even if your system otherwise has plenty of memory and plenty of GDI resources.  (These systemwide limits are apparently because Windows may allocate device-dependent bitmaps in the video card's memory.)

The solution is simply to use device-independent bitmaps (DIBs) instead (although these may not offer quite as good of a performance).  [This KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/230492) describes how to pick the optimal DIB format for a device.

Other candidates for resource limits (from others' answers and my own research):

- GDI resources (from this answer) - easily checked with [GDIView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/gdi%5Fhandles.html)
- Virtual memory fragmentation (from this answer)
- Desktop heap - see [here](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-desktopheap.html) or [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=5cfc9b74-97aa-4510-b4b9-b2dc98c8ed8b&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 4):

A more common cause this error than any of those you've listed is fragmentation of Virtual Memory Space.  This a situation where whilst the total free memory is quite reasonable the free space is fragmented with various bits of the virtual memory space being currently allocated.  Hence you can get an out of memory error when a request for memory cannot be satisfied by a single contiguous block despite the being enough in total free.

Comment: That should be fairly easily checkable by trying the same thing from a fresh reboot. One would think they would have tried that before posting it as a question on SO (but dumber things have happened...)

Comment: @T.E.D. : A reboot isn't any more effective than simply killing the faulting process and trying again. Each process has its own fresh Virtual memory space when it is first created. The problem usually arises naturally in a long running app or quickly where there is a mixture of large and small chunks of memory being allocated and deallocated fairly rapidily whith different lifetimes. Its usually an indicator that some chunk of code ought be maintaining a list of buffers to re-use rather than constantly allocating and releasing memory.

Comment: Using FastMM in Delphi is better at preventing virtual memory fragmentation.

Answer (score 4):

Check all the possibilities.

GDI-problems can be monitored using the free [GDIView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/gdi_handles.html) utility. Its a single file that users can start without a installer.

Also, install the [ProcessExplorer](http://download.sysinternals.com/Files/ProcessExplorer.zip) on the machine concerned.

If you have no access to the machine, ask the user to make screenshots of the status monitored by the applications. Very likeley, this will give you some hint.

Comment: GDIView gives <s>interesting</s><u>impressive</u> details about "the GDI objects".

Answer (score 0):

My answer may be a little bit late but, from my late experience with that same issue, doing all the tests, going step by step, creating DC, releasing it, using `DIBSection` instead of `CompatibleBitmap`, using leak GDI/Memory tools, etc.

In the end (LOL) I found that:

I was switching the priority of these two calls, then the whole problem was fixed.

```
DeleteDC(hdc);       //do it first (always before deleting objects)
DeleteObject(obj);
```