# Delphi EOutOfResources (GDIError)

Tags: delphi, gdi, limits, eoutofresources

I have written an application in which I find ocasionally EOutofResources errors
raised by GDIError method of Graphics unit when saving TBitmap32 to a stream.

As far as I know it can come from gdi limits or heap limits.
i know that for the process there is a default limit of 10000 handles. 
So my application according to the task manager reports only 620.

I have downloaded and run Desktop Heap Information Monitor Tool which reported this:

```
Desktop Heap Information Monitor Tool (Version 8.1.2925.0)
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
-------------------------------------------------------------
  Session ID:    0 Total Desktop: (  7360 KB -   11 desktops)

  WinStation\Desktop            Heap Size(KB)    Used Rate(%)
-------------------------------------------------------------
  WinSta0\Default                    3072             44.5
  WinSta0\Disconnect                   64              4.5
  WinSta0\Winlogon                    128             10.2
  Service-0x0-3e7$\Default            512             29.1
  Service-0x0-3e4$\Default            512              6.8
  Service-0x0-3e5$\Default            512              6.8
  SAWinSta\SADesktop                  512              0.5
  __X78B95_89_IW\__A8D9S1_42_ID       512              0.5
  Service-0x0-1ae39$\Default          512              2.4
  Service-0x0-12d284a7$\Default       512              2.5
  Service-0x0-1312b6d4$\Default       512             15.0
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

As above I have used only 44% of the desktop heap in winsta0.

Besides this error is raised from time to time. it never reaches mentioned limits.
How can i check where the problem is? What causes raising this error?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you're leaking bitmap handles?

Comment: I think you should post the relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have a resource and/or memory leak.

**Finding memory leaks**
If you use the debug version of FastMM, it will show you a report of memory leaks when your program closes.

The following article should help you out:
http://wiert.wordpress.com/2009/07/29/delphi-fastmm-using-fastmm4-for-debugging-your-memory-allocations-part-1-introduction/

**Finding resource leaks**
Note that FastMM, while an essential tool for finding **memory leaks** does not find resource leaks.
AQTime can find those, and it has a 30 day trail period. Check it out at:
http://smartbear.com/products/development-tools/performance-profiling/

If you want an open source resource leak tool try: http://www.kbasm.com/denomo.html

Good hunting.

Answer (score 2):

This probably isn't a resource error at all. Sometimes Delphi will report GDI errors that  can't be translated into a specific error message as out-of-resources. See the implementation of GDIError in Graphics.pas.

If you can reproduce this in the IDE, the best way to find out where/why it happens is probably to enable the Use Debug DCUs option in the compiler settings and have the Stop On Delphi Exceptions debugger option enabled while running your app.

Comment: `can't be translated` (or: that's too boring to translate), as mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2181633/2932052)